# Smallest Convex polygon around point

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, math

I got a bunch of 2d points. What I'm trying to find is the smallest polygon around (created from minimal set of points that fully enclose) one specific point. I tried to use convex hull and Voronoi but none of them produce the results I'm looking for and I'm running out of ideas...

What I want is to find are the lines (in red) that represent the smallest convex polygon around a point (in green) as demonstrated on the image below:

[image]

Another example:

[image]

Any code, suggestions, or known algorithm would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Are there any restrictions in terms of how many vertices the polygon can have? By "smallest" you mean surface and not circumference, right? Oh, and how is this problem related to c++ or c?

Comment: by "the smallest polygon" do you mean, the polygon with the smallest area or the polygon with the smallest number of points, or something else?

Comment: Please clarify "smallest". Smallest number of vertices? Smallest perimeter? Smallest area?

Comment: That should be on [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com) section

Comment: Smallest amount of points (I also update the question).

Comment: @McBob So is it not always 3 or impossible? In the first example i can see a polygon that contains the green point with only 3 vertices ...

Comment: I need to solve the solution using C/C++ since the points are entered by the user from an app.

Comment: I agree with @FantasticMrFox. Point has no area, so smallest polygon is always a triangle. But if points are actually spheres with an area, that makes the question a totally different.

Comment: @Fantastic: If the point is colinear with two vertices of the triangle, then you'd need another point on the other side of the line from the third vertex of the triangle, forming a quadrilateral. That's if you require the point to be strictly inside, not on the perimeter.

Comment: Do you actually need minimum area, or do you just need "not including any other points - i.e. "does not look wrong"?

Comment: @IanAbbott Yes, but select a different point? I don't think the actual question is clear. But if the restriction is a polygon with the minimum number of points, then the first example is wrong, because there are 3 vertex polygons that can contain that dot. In an edge case where you only have co-linear points, you are right, minimum would be 4. But example 1 is not one of those cases.

Comment: @Ian Abbott You are exactly right +1

Comment: In your first example, there is a triangle of black points that contain the green point, although it looks like its area is larger than the red quadrilateral you drew. But you have stated that you are looking for the fewest number of vertices, so the example is wrong.

Comment: @Ian Abbott Humm... or, should I say minimal set of points that fully enclose the green dot then...

Comment: This question belongs on another Stack Exchange site: [Computational science](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/), [Maths](https://math.stackexchange.com/), [software engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/), [signal processing](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/), etc.

Comment: In the first example, the triangle would actually have smaller area than the red quadrilateral. I measured your red quadrilateral's area as 4432 pixels and the alternative triangle's area as 4255 pixels (approximately).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: Another possible criterion for "smallest" could be to minimize the total distance from the target point to the vertices of a polygon that contains it.

Comment: Or the "smallest" could be to find the polygon containing the point whose furthest point is closest to the target point, i.e. minimize the radius of the bounding circle. The red quadrilateral in your first example matches that criterion. For this criterion, you can just sort points by distance from target point.

Comment: @Ian Abbott I tried that at some point, the problem I was having is that I didn't know when to stop including points. I ended up with too much or too little; unable to close the polygon (in some cases) + I didn't know the connection order.

Comment: Yes, you could find a non-convex intermediate solution containing vertices inside the convex hull. In that case, try eliminating each convex hull vertex in turn to see if the remaining vertices also form an intermediate non-convex or a final convex solution. Repeat until you get a convex solution. The solution might not be unique or might not exist.

Comment: The simplest would be to order the points by distance (perhaps using a heap) then take the nearest point, and the next nearest point that has the cross-product to place it opposite (90-270 deg rel), then use cross-product to get side (0-180 or 180-360) and order the points so they are on one side, and select  the nearest third point on the opposite side (0-180) to both of those. This is almost certainly not the smallest, but is probably the least silly.

Comment: This is an algorithm. Implement it in any language you like.

Comment: Isn't this NP-Complete? The choice of one point may effects the value of the selection of another point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start from any black point in your diagram, let's call it A. Draw the line from point A to the green point G. Now draw the line from point A to any other point A1, A2,... . If in a clockwise sense, this line is after line AG, ignore it. From all other lines choose the one that forms the smallest angle with line AG. Now move point A to the next point. Repeat until you are visiting a point for the second time.

Comment: Nope, smallest angle does *not* give you the smallest circumference. It's a functional heuristic, but has the potential for very bad results: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePgEU.png Note that I wouldn't waste that much time trying to solve it perfectly I believe it's NP-Complete.